# What is the best hardware/software available to give online classes

Tags: technology-in-education

I would like to give some private math classes online and for this purpose I currently use this pen: [Wacom Bamboo Pen Tablet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002OOWC3I). The problem is I cannot see directly where I am writing. I'm thinking about buying a [Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007M506WS) and using its pen to give my classes. I would like to know if there is another tablet available which would better suit my purposes, or if there is good software to use with Galaxy note in order to give classes.

Thanks

**EDIT**

What I'm looking for is software similar to this [site](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IjJxjcbVM0w) [the video is in portuguese].

Comment: You have forgotten to include links, it appears... **Also:** Can you specify which classes you are teaching (topic, students, how much is online) and what your *purposes* are?

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I would like to give private online classes of mathematics and use a software as a "blackboard".

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I'm looking for something similar to this site: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IjJxjcbVM0w

Answer (score 1):

The youtube video you linked to is a [screencast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screencast). You can create such videos with [Camtasia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camtasia_Studio) but also with the [VLC player](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player) you can record a screencast (Camtasia offers features to edit an recorded screencast which you might find useful). Google "screencast" or "record + screencast + [your operating system]" and you will find a lot of resources about this topic. See also [this wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_screencasting_software).

For making drawings, you need a software like [xournal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xournal). See [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_notetaking_software).